# Creating users across all cluster nodes

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, cluster, aix

Is there a way to add a user across all cluster nodes via command line? I have the manual instructions from IBM [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPHQG_7.1.0/com.ibm.powerha.admngd/ha_admin_add_ua_allnodes.htm) (and listed below) and found instructions for listing the users (cl_lsuser), but nothing for adding.

> To add an LDAP user or an AIX operating system user to all nodes in a cluster >using the C-SPOC utility, complete the following steps on any cluster node:
>
> 1. From the command line, enter smit cl_admin.
> 2. In SMIT, select Security and Users > Users in a PowerHA SystemMirror cluster > Add a User to the Cluster, and press Enter.
> 3. In the Select an Authentication and
>    registry mode window, select the mode and press Enter.
> 4. Enter data in
>    the applicable fields to set up the account, and press Enter.

Is there a commandline solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will be :

```
smcli sysmirror/mkuser -c *clustername* –R ldap *username*
```

Or to create it from the local file system instead of LDAP :

```
smcli sysmirror/mkuser -c *clustername* –R files *username*
```

You can also refer to the following link for more information :

[IBM mkuser command](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPHQG_7.1.0/com.ibm.powerha.director/dir_cmd_mkuser.htm)

Regards